# AttributeError: 'guiCreate' object has no attribute 'master' - Why can't i access functions from another class?

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter

I have three different classes: One is called guiCreate and the other is called iconBlockGen as well as main. Whenever an something is true in iconBlockGen then iconBlockGen will call a function (addPayment()) from a class that was created in gui (guiCreate) that adds a new item to the list.

I have tried creating objects in many different and hacky ways but i get the same issue no matter what. Code:

blockgen.py:

```
import gui
import main

class iconBlockGen():

    def startLoop(self):
        gui.guiCreate.addPayment() # this is the command that causes the issue since it doesn't know know what the attribute is or whatever
```

gui.py

```
import blockgen
import tkinter as tk

class guiCreate(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):

        pad = 3
        x = master.winfo_screenwidth() - pad
        y = master.winfo_screenheight() - pad

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.recievingAdress = Listbox(self.master, width=int(x / 40), height=int(y / 24))
        self.recievingAdress.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        self.recievingAdress.place(x=x / 1.4, y=y / 10)

        self.master = master
        self._geom = '200x200+0+0'
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            x, y))
        self.layout(x, y)


    def addPayment(self):
        self.recievingAdress.insert(1, 1515)

def test():

    icxObject = blockgen.iconBlockGen()

    root = Tk()
    t = guiCreate(root)
    handlerThrd = threading.Thread(target=icxObject.startLoop)
    handlerThrd.start()
    root.mainloop()
```

main.py

```
import gui

def main():
    gui.guiCreate.test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is `test` part of `guiCreate` class? if so, should except `self` as first parameter. If not, how can you call `gui.guiCreate.test()`?

Comment: it is outside guiCreate so no it is not appart of the class. I call that function from main, which works somehow.

Answer (score 0):

you showd send to the start loop function the gui create *object* and than the function coud access add payment method

now you access the class insted of the object

Comment: And what is that exactly? Do i just pass it 'object'?